# Missing semicolon in class declaration

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I suspect this is a very minor issue, but I have spent several hours trying to fix it and have not found anything.

In Game.h (a header file), I have the following:

```
#pragma once

#include "PlayEngine.h"

class Game {

public:
    int Init();
    int Run();
    int Shutdown();

private:
    enum State { ST_MENU, ST_PLAYING } state;
    PlayEngine* playengine_;
};
```

The compiler throws a syntax error on `PlayEngine* playengine_`, complaining that there is a missing `;` before the `*`. PlayEngine is a class I have defined in other places.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `PlayEngine.h` directly or indirectly attempt to include `Game.h`?

Comment: This code looks all right, so the error is probably in the code where you've defined `PlayEngine` (which we'll hope is in/included by `PlayEngine.h`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
#include "PlayEngine.h"
```

with

```
class PlayEngine;
```

A declaration is enough for this case. (and I'm betting the source is a circular inclusion)

Comment: Wow, thanks! Yeah, upon looking at my code more closely, I found a circular inclusion. (Upvoting requires 15 karma, I'll try and remember to return to upvote once I can)

Answer (score -1):

Remove state at the end of your enum declaration. and declare the variable separate.

```
#pragma once
#include "PlayEngine.h"  
class Game {  
    public:     
        int Init();     
        int Run();     
        int Shutdown();  
    private:     
        enum State { ST_MENU, ST_PLAYING };  
        State state;   
        PlayEngine* playengine_; 
};
```